# antivirus update through terminal

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

Trying again in 5 secs...
ClamAV update process started at Sat Jul 25 08:21:14 2015
WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
WARNING: Can't get information about db.local.clamav.net: Name or service not known
those lines are showing whenever I try to update ClamAV

Answer (score 0):

On terminal run :

```
sudo freshclam
```